# Xamarin - how to create horizontal line with centered text (XAML)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying this for many days but didn't succeed. I'm trying to do the same than this image:
[image]

So my intention is to create in XAML, a simple bar with centered text to be added on the Sign Up Page and Register Page but I really don't how to do it on Xamarin Essentials 1.7.5 & .NET Standard 2.1 using XAML. This project is built on Visual Studio 2022 using C# as a programming language. Tried to create a Grid with 2 rows like this but didn't work as expected.

```
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="OR" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Grid with three columns:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,auto,*">
      <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="BoxView">
                  <Setter Property="Color" Value="Gray"/>
                  <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand"/>
                  <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                  <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
      </Grid.Resources>
      <BoxView Grid.Column="0"/>
      <Label Text="OR" Grid.Column="1"/>
      <BoxView Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

This creates a line with a "OR" in the middle. You could add some Margin to the BoxViews so that it fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisRoeder but it's not working as expected. I need to add Grid.Column="1" on Label Section and height="1" seems is not working...

Comment: "It's not working as expected" is a very bad description of what you are seeing. Elaborate?

Comment: So as you can see the size of the line must be according to the text size so it's not exactly the same than the original picture I sent as there was a thin line text using higher size.

Comment: I've updated the code. Add "VerticalOptions="Center"" to the BoxViews. So you get thin lines.